# Using string concatenation in Oracle SQL Developer not outputting in desired format

Tags: sql, database, oracle, concatenation, oracle-xe

I have a CUSTOMER table and have to concatenate the FirstName and LastName columns seperated by a comma and a space ', ' into one new column called CustomerName.

The desired output is something like:

```
CustomerName
----------------------
FirstName1, LastName1
FirstName2, LastName2
FirstName3, LastName3
```

But my actual output is:

```
CustomerName
----------------------------------------
FirstName1                    , LastName1
FirstName2                    , LastName2
FirstName3                    , LastName3
```

I have tried nesting the CONCAT function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(FirstName, ', '),LastName) "CustomerName"
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

I have also tried using the double pipe concatenation operator (||):

```
SELECT FirstName ||', '|| LastName "CustomerName"
FROM Customer;
```

Both Sections of code result in the same output where each column is separated by a lot of whitespace opposed to just a space.

Comment: What are the data types of `FirstName` and `LastName`?  It looks like `FirstName` is defined as a `char` rather than a `varchar2`.

Comment: @JustinCave The datatype is Char for both FirstName and LastName

Comment: That is almost certainly a mistake.  There is basically never a reason to use `char` for something like a name since that forces Oracle to pad the result stored in the column with spaces out to the specified length.  Names are variable length so they should be stored in `varchar2` columns.

Comment: Yes VarChar is definitely better for names as I now see. The whitespace is now gone after changing the datatypes.

Comment: Even if it's defined as VARCHAR, as suggested by @JustinCave there's nothing to prevent extra spaces being stored.  Use TRIM.  TRIM(FirstName) || ', '|| TRIM(LastName)

Comment: It should be VARCHAR2. The documentation says not to use VARCHAR as it is reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like your datatype is just char and not var or alot of space has been saved ,the best would be to chnage your datatype to var,if not you can trim them :

```
SELECT TRIM(FirstName) ||', '|| TRIM(LastName)  "CustomerName"
FROM Customer;
```

Comment: Yes the datatypes for FirstName and LastName are CHAR so that would make sense as to why there is whitespace being saved. I may just change them to VARCHAR2. Or will use Trim() as you have suggested.

Comment: yup that would be the best  if you can change the datatype ,

Comment: *Update* Trimming did not seem to work. However, once I changed the datatypes to varchar for FirstName and LastName in the DDL the whitespace is now gone. Thank you,  appreciate the hand.

Comment: look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fec6d31900d17e11d0e90c2d1ac2b66a) , trim works , that's weird it didn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to trim value before concat.
You have this issue in simple reason - db stores value with fixed length, so when you select it - it fill not used part with empty value - white space